# Is there a way to show where missed coverage is on karma coverage

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, istanbul, karma-coverage

I have an Angular app and I'm giving testing a go but it's a nightmare to find where the coverage is needed.

the output shows the following:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================      
Statements   : 91.67% ( 22/24 )
Branches     : 75% ( 3/4 )
Functions    : 75% ( 3/4 )
Lines        : 90.48% ( 19/21 )
================================================================================
```

Is there a way to see where these statements, branches, functions and lines are that are not covered?

e.g. some output that says

```
Statements:
1. file: some/file/name.js line:03
2. file: some/file/name.js line:06
```

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular CLI creates code coverage reports when using the following command (see [Enable code coverage reports](https://angular.io/guide/testing#enable-code-coverage-reports)).

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

When the tests are complete, the command creates a new `/coverage` folder in the project or it overwrites its content if it existed before. Open the `index.html` file inside the `/coverage` folder to see a report with your source code and code coverage values.